# Маленький совет

Tags: интернет-магазин

Пишу скрипт интернет магазина, дошло дело до купонов и скидок.
В панели управления магазинов, раздел "Заказы" нужно как можно детальнее описать тип скидки.
Изначально я думал делать ссылку на запить скидки, но так как скидка может позже редактироваться или вообще быть удалена, это оказалось плохой идеей.
Думал добавить несколько полей в таблице заказов, но очень хочется увеличивать таблицу.

Как лучше сохрать информацию об использованных купонах в заказах?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно поддержать только один вид скидки, то это одно поле в заказе с ссылкой на купон в справочнике (который раз введен, не редактируется) - таблице купонов.

А вообще скидок может быть великое множество:

- по товару (сезонные, распродажи)
- по количеству товара (берете две, третья бесплатно) или разного товара
- по сумме заказа (дисконтная карта, купон)
- подарки (нулевая цена)
- ...

Чтобы поддержать все варианты должен быть сложный расчет и ограничиться одной ссылкой не получится. И для всего заказа понадобится ссылка, а может быть и не одна, и для каждой позиции в заказе тоже...